# php json - Get Only first element from Array

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I'm writing code to show data from themoviedb.org API, but still failed to get correct results. I dont know what're wrongs to my PHP codes, but **below code just give me one result from array**, it should be 3 items. **Below code are for testing only** :

```
<?php
    ...
    $data = json_decode($result, true);
    $data_movie = array($data['results']);   
    $i = 0;     
    foreach ($data_movie as $key => $val)
    {
       echo $val[$i]['poster_path']."<br/>";
       $i++;
    }           
?>
```

But if i do `print_r($data_movie)`, the data are available...

The **Json** structure:

```
{
    "page": 1,
    "results": [
        {
            "poster_path": "/6bCplVkhowCjTHXWv49UjRPn0eK.jpg",
            "adult": false,
            "overview": "Fearing the actions of a god-like Super Hero left unchecked, Gotham City’s own formidable, forceful vigilante takes on Metropolis’s most revered, modern-day savior, while the world wrestles with what sort of hero it really needs. And with Batman and Superman at war with one another, a new threat quickly arises, putting mankind in greater danger than it’s ever known before.",
            "release_date": "2016-03-23",
            "genre_ids": [
                28,
                12,
                14,
                878
            ],
            "id": 209112,
            "original_title": "Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice",
            "original_language": "en",
            "title": "Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice",
            "backdrop_path": "/15PbZtjRJ4zgQA8XS0otL70piQi.jpg",
            "popularity": 7.969661,
            "vote_count": 42,
            "video": false,
            "vote_average": 5.68
        },
        {
            "poster_path": "/tSFBh9Ayn5uiwbUK9HvD2lrRgaQ.jpg",
            "adult": false,
            "overview": "Beatrice Prior and Tobias Eaton venture into the world outside of the fence and are taken into protective custody by a mysterious agency known as the Bureau of Genetic Welfare.",
            "release_date": "2016-03-09",
            "genre_ids": [
                12,
                878
            ],
            "id": 262504,
            "original_title": "The Divergent Series: Allegiant",
            "original_language": "en",
            "title": "The Divergent Series: Allegiant",
            "backdrop_path": "/jaoDlr7XGGtHs1VpN9macrbXheO.jpg",
            "popularity": 4.624446,
            "vote_count": 42,
            "video": false,
            "vote_average": 6.81
        },
        {
            "poster_path": "/d936U33f5n6bRtzDHh1gmDdriKr.jpg",
            "adult": false,
            "overview": "Waking up from a car accident, a young woman finds herself in the basement of a man who says he's saved her life from a chemical attack that has left the outside uninhabitable.",
            "release_date": "2016-03-09",
            "genre_ids": [
                18,
                9648,
                878,
                53
            ],
            "id": 333371,
            "original_title": "10 Cloverfield Lane",
            "original_language": "en",
            "title": "10 Cloverfield Lane",
            "backdrop_path": "/u7GyYxTNx8LDYpma605YZvjdOVp.jpg",
            "popularity": 2.90869,
            "vote_count": 10,
            "video": false,
            "vote_average": 2.95
        }
    ],
    "dates": {
        "maximum": "2016-03-27",
        "minimum": "2016-03-06"
    },
    "total_pages": 5,
    "total_results": 97
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$i` counter is useless:

```
$data = json_decode($result, true);
$data_movie = $data['results'];
foreach ($data_movie as $key => $val) {
    echo $val['poster_path'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your way of looping is strange, why aren't you just doing this:

```
<?php    
foreach ($data['results'] as $d) {
   print_r($d);
}           
?>
```

Comment: I don't think his way of iteration over an array is strange.

Comment: @Ionut : you don't think using for_each and not using $key/$value is strange ?

Comment: It goes both ways, you can use keys and values or not. There's nothing strange about that. That's what I said. But seems that to @Sakuto is something strange when using key and value. Depends on what you need the key.

Comment: The strange part is not the key value, the strange (and non working) part is using a `$i` counter to loop on.

Comment: Oh, okay. My mistake. Sometimes I use a counter too. For a different reason in the loop. Not for iteration of an array. Maybe that's what he's doing too. But showed the minimum of code to explain his problem. Anyway, that's not what the OP asked. The weird/strange thing I think is the use of  $data_movie = array($data['results']);   When clearly $data['results'] is already an array.